# f string and extended unpacking

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, linux-mint

I am trying to do extended unpacking of tuple with `*` syntax. I'm trying to format string with `f''` string syntax. None of those work in visual-studio-code python3.7.3 linuxmint64 system.

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

a, *b = l
print(a, b)
```

Here is the error :

```
line 3

    a, *b = l
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Thank you avariant for editing my code, I am new here and do not know much how to post correctly.

Comment: I have dual boot computer and I tried the same code on my windows platform and both: f string formatting and extended unpacking, actually works properly, none of them shows the same SyntaxError

Comment: Thank you Arkistarvh Kltzuonstev too for helping to format my question correctly :)

Answer (score 0):

Your Code:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

a, *b = l
print(a, b)
```

The above code won't as the correct syntax is b=[*l]. The * is used to unpack a list.
So if you want to have some values in both a and b  so the code below...

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
d = [3,2,1]
a , b = [*l] , [*d]  # Here [*l] unpacks l in a list and assign it to a and
                     # and [*d] unpacks d in a list and assign it to b 

print(a , b)
```

Hope this helps...